# Jquery: button value change not working but changes shows on inspect element

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery for input [type=submit] value changed.

I have four to five html `<form>`. 2 forms which is on header and body its working as i want. But other 2 form which is on footer and contact us page it not working. I mean input value not changing. when i saw inspect element. **Inspect element** code showing value change but in front view value not changing.

My Jquery version is **jquery-3.3.1.min.js**

I tried this code:

```
$('#footer-btn').attr("value", 'Please wait..');
$('#footer-btn').prop("value", 'Please wait..');
$('#id input[type=submit]').prop("value", 'Please wait..');
$('#id input[type=submit]').attr("value", 'Please wait..');
```

**but same code two forms changed his input value and 2 others form not changing his input value 
Please solve the errros.
**

[image]

Comment: .html() or .text() you shall use as what you trying to change is button for input it show the value on compile for button it show what inside the tag your code explain the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you actually want to change button text, but you are doing it through `.prop() or .attr()` using `value`, which is incorrect.

To change the text of button,you need to use `.html()` or `.text()`

```
$('#footer-btn').html('Please wait..');
$('#footer-btn').text('Please wait..');
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#footer-btn').html('Please wait..');
  $('#footer-btn1').text('Please wait for 5 second..');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="footer-btn">Click Me!</button>

<button id="footer-btn1">Click Me too!</button>
```

Comment: wow thanks Its working. But what is the issue with .attr('value', 'text') and .prop('value','text') not working. 2 times working and 3rd and 4th time not working

Comment: I meant i have 4 html forms in 1st is on header, 2nd is on sidebar, 3rd is on footer and 4th is on contact us page. 1st and 2nd attr() worked but 3rd and 4th same code not working

Comment: @Inderjeet  still didn't get you. Please ask a new question with all form HTML as well as your code(jQuery). Also, explain that what you are trying to achieve actually?